# Code Coverage Tool for C# with VS Code for Mac OSx

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, visual-studio-mac

How can I check the code coverage of my C# Unit Tests in VS Code?

The Code Coverage tool that I've used (because of it's simplicity, it is usable in the terminal) is [MiniCover](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/minicover). The MiniCover Tool is, however, as of Jan 24 2018, only doing line coverage, and is not integrated into the IDE.

Comment: See documentation for a tool you want to use. That should be sufficient... If not, there are probably a couple of tutorials and youtube videos for the tool.

Comment: We are using https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet as a coverage tool. Coverage Gutters extension for VS Code does a UI support for generated reports. Works in MacOS

Comment: Off topic?  Seriously SO.  get to 21st century

Comment: This is a top google result when searching for code coverage for vscode.  It should be opened and answered. FWIW, I found a great Scott Hanselman post but found that coverage gutters doesnt support c# currently. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/automatic-unit-testing-in-net-core-plus-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: We certainly have other posts like it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70321465/how-to-get-code-coverage-from-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2022-community-edition

Comment: This could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946038/how-do-i-see-dotnet-line-coverage-in-vscode .