# How can I view line coverage in Visual Studio Code for .NET projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Is there a visual method to display line coverage for .NET code in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly** [.NET Core Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer) and [Coverage Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters) extensions is required in VSCode.

**Secondly** in `MyProjectLocation/.vscode/settings.json` add these settings:

```
{
   "dotnet-test-explorer.testArguments": "/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov /p:CoverletOutput=lcov.info",
   "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "**/*MyTestProject.csproj"
}
```

this will generate lcov.info file which is required for [Coverage Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters).

**Third** step would be to install the [Coverlet MSBuild](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet) package from NuGet to testing project. This could be done with `dotnet add package coverlet.msbuild` command in terminal.

*After this installation and running tests with [.NET Core Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer) you will see code coverage by clicking `watch` at the bottom of VSCode:*

[image: watch]

*You should be able to see coverage like this:*
[image]