# How to get .NET code coverage analysis in VS Code?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, coverlet

I wrote NUnit tests to test .NET code. Now I want to see my coverage statistics in VS Code.

Is there any way to get visual/textual coverage analysis for .NET unit tests in VS Code?

Maybe there is some good extension for that?

Comment: The coverage tools you already use provide text output. What tools are you talking about? Isn't it enough to read their output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, I don't know any extensions for that in VS Code. But I found another way to see coverage stats in VS Code.

All you need to do is:

**Install** [.NET report generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows) in terminal with command:

`dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool`

**Add** [Coverlet MS build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/coverlet.msbuild) package from NuGet to testing project

`dotnet add package coverlet.msbuild`

**Run** dotnet tests from terminal with command:

`dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov /p:CoverletOutput=lcov.info`

**Add** configuration to `tasks.json` file in `.vscode` folder (If file doesn't exist create new one):

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Generate coverage stats",
            "command": "reportgenerator",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "-reports:${workspaceFolder}/YourUnitTestProjectFolder/lcov.info",
                "-targetdir:${workspaceFolder}/YourUnitTestProjectFolder/covstats"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Launch** task in VS Code by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P` and executing `Tasks: Run task` command.
[image: Tasks: Run task]

And then **press** `Generate coverage stats`

[image: Generate coverage stats]

In your test project should appear `covstats` folder which contain `index.html` file. With right mouse button **click** `Show preview` on that file. Coverage analysis will appear.

[image]

*Creds to: https://jasonwatmore.com/net-vs-code-xunit-setup-unit-testing-code-coverage-in-aspnet-core .*

Comment: So your real question is how to view Coverlet output in VS Code? Googling for `VS Code Coverlet` brings up [a Coverlet extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=urbanoanderson.vscode-coverlet), an [article by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/automatic-unit-testing-in-net-core-plus-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-code) that points to the [Coverage Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters) extension.

Comment: Report Generator is mentioned in the .NET Docs, at [Use code coverage for unit testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows)

Comment: @Panagiotis-Kanavos Thanks for the comment. Currently, I haven't found how to preview coverage reports with coverage gutters. With coverage gutters, I can only visually see line coverage like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946038/how-do-i-see-dotnet-line-coverage-in-vscode .